# How to render logo and login/search box is same row

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

code below renders search form in below logo:

```
 LOGO IMAGE

Logon or register

Search:
```

How to chage it so that Login/Search is rendered after logo in same row:

```
               Logon or register
LOGO IMAGE        
               Search:
```

site.master contains:

```
<div id="header" style="margin: 0; background-color: white; width: 100%">
   <a href="http://mysite.com">
     <img alt='' style='width:30%' src='/Store/Logo' />
     </a>
   <div >
      <p class="accBoxUnloggedOther">
           <a href="/logon">Logon</a>
             or <a href="/register">
              Register</a></p>
      <br />
      <form action="/Store/Search" style="margin:0">
        <input class="searchfield" id="Search"  />
        <input class="button blue bigrounded" type="submit" value="Search... " />
        </form>
     </div>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style="float:right;"` on the inner div. But you should try to avoid using inline CSS. It leads to a maintenance nightmare.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyqca/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the elements you want in the same line in a `<div>` tag and the image in another `<div>`